# Transport dt_socket 8787 already in use

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to run a Server and Client application in Jetty server on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. The server starts without any problem and I used the following command

$ mvn jetty:run

on issuing this command the first line was

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787

But when I launched the client I got the following error

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Aborted
```

Looks something to do with transport dt_socket. I have no understanding what it is and how to use another address for Client?

**Edit 1**

jetty-maven-plugin from pom.xml for client looks like this

```
<build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- Specific jetty-maven-plugin configuration for running Jetty during
        development. None of its goals are run in a normal build lifecycle. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            <extraClasspath>${basedir}/src/test/resources/</extraClasspath>
          </webAppConfig>
          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>${servlet.port}</port>
              <host>0.0.0.0</host>
            </connector>
          </connectors>
          <reload>manual</reload>
          <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

My assumption is some Jetty is starting in debug mode and trying to attach the debugger at port 8787 which is already bound to debugger of Server.

Comment: is it possible that you have a previous instance of jetty already running that perhaps crashed?, as it is linux you can try kill -9 <pid>, and you can run ps aux | grep jetty to know the pid

Comment: @OscarG I have to run a client and server on same machine, see edited question.

Comment: then it looks like you're trying to start two server instances listening on the same port, if you are running a client it does not need to start listening into any port, instead it gets connected to the server on the defined port. Am I understanding your issue right?

Comment: @OscarG No, to my understanding it has something it do with Java VM. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jetty does NOT automatically starts the debugger. You most likely have set the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to include -Xdebug parameters. Check with 'echo $MAVEN_OPTS' and you will see something like:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

You can't run two maven processes which both try to debug on port 8787. So change your global MAVEN_OPTS (in .bash_profile when running on osx) or change your MAVEN_OPTS for your second terminal session:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me - someone sent me their `MAVEN_OPTS` export and I put it in my .bash_profile and then I couldn't start more than one mvn:jetty.

Answer (score 9):

Enter the below command in terminal / command prompt

`killall -9 java`

It will kill all the java processes. You will be able to use the port then.

Comment: Worked for me, perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration inside jetty plugin

```
<configuration>
    <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>9090</port>
        </connector>
    </connectors>
</configuration>
```

Or alternatively, run `jetty` from command line this way

```
mvn -Djetty.port=9090 jetty:run
```

Comment: Interesting, it should work according to the docs - https://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin

Comment: The pom.xml has already port 8084 configured of Jetty. Looks to me the problem is in "JDWP Transport dt_socket"

Comment: And are you trying to remotely debug Jetty?If yes, how your command looks?

Comment: Edited the question, see if I have been able explain the problem bette.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you run two servers on the same port, so you should change port number of one of them

Comment: No, to my understanding it has something it do with Java VM. docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html

Comment: And are you running tests on it?Because Jetty automatically starts in debug mode when running tests on it, so this could cause the conflict

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36955/discussion-between-coding-crow-and-petr-mensik)